# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse' to type 'DragDropExample.Circle' Exception: System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm working with C# WPF and have two `StackPanels`. In `StackPanel[0]` there is a `circle(Ellipse)`, using drag and drop (Note: Also I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to copy with dragging).

I want to copy the circle from first `StackPanel` to the second `StackPanel`, but when I want to apply this it give me an error.Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse' to type 'DragDropExample.Circle'

I don't have any problem when I move the circle from the first `StackPanel` to the second `StackPanel`, I just have problem while I want to copy.

Code:

```
private void panel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    try 
    { 
        if (e.Handled == false)
        {
            Panel _panel = (Panel)sender;
            UIElement _element = (UIElement)e.Data.GetData("Object");
            if (_panel != null && _element != null)
            {
                // Get the panel that the element currently belongs to,
                // then remove it from that panel and add it the Children of
                // the panel that its been dropped on.
                Panel _parent = (Panel)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(_element);
                if (_parent != null)
                {
                    if (e.KeyStates == DragDropKeyStates.ControlKey && e.AllowedEffects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Copy))
                    {
                        Circle _circle = new Circle((Circle)_element);
                        _panel.Children.Add(_circle);
                        //Set the value to return to the DoDragDrop call
                        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                    }
                    else if (e.AllowedEffects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move))
                    {
                        _parent.Children.Remove(_element);
                        _panel.Children.Add(_element);
                        //set the value to return to the DoDragDrop call
                        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Circle a custom control?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "in `StackPanel[0]` there is a `circle(Ellipse)`" Is it a `Circle`, or is it an `Ellipse`? The error appears to be because it's actually an `Ellipse` but you're expecting it to be a `Circle`...

Comment: @IbrahimXalil You still haven't told us what `Circle` actually is.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have two StackPanels first one will be StackPanel[0] and second one will be StackPanel[1], Yes the circle is an Ellipse, the Circle is a custom control.

Comment: @IbrahimXalil: So where are you actually creating an instance of `Circle`? If what's already in the stack panel is an `Ellipse`, why would you expect to be able to cast it to a `Circle`?